# Does Sequelize.js escape input for SQL injection by default?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If I try to use Sequelize.js like this:

```
model.user.create
(
    {
        username : user_name,
        password : hashed_password
    },
    {
        attribute : ['id'],
        raw : true
    }
);
```

Will Sequelize.js ensure user_name will not cause any SQL injection or should I make sure to escape it before handing it off to Sequelize.js ? (in model, both username and password are just `type : Sequelize.TEXT`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I see in the [source code](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js#L189) for Sequelize v4 and v5, the `insertQuery()` function is escaping everything it can in the generated query. Here is the actual [`escape()` function implementation](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/v4/lib/sql-string.js#L22).